# mysql-phpmyadmin create event get error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to add new event to rename a table in my DB use by phpmyadmine, and it will give me the errors :

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near     SET @tablename = 'Today Raw Data';SET @newname = ' raw Data'; SELECT @query' at line3

my code is :

```
select @yesterday := date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day);

SET @tablename = 'Today Raw Data';
SET @newname = ' raw Data';

SELECT @query := CONCAT('RENAME TABLE `', @tablename, '` TO `',@yesterday,@newname, '`');

PREPARE STMT FROM @query;
EXECUTE STMT;
```

Answer (score -1):

`CREATE TABLE alter (first_day DATE, last_day DATE);`

How to fix it: Just because the word `alter` is reserved does not mean it cannot be used, it just has special requirements to use it as the MySQL engine is trying to call the functionality for the alter command. To fix the issue, you will want to surround the word with backticks  ``` `` ```, this is usually the button just to the left of the "1" button on the keyboard. The code block below shows how the code will need to look in order to run properly.

```
CREATE TABLE `alter` (first_day DATE, last_day DATE);
```

Missing Data
Sometimes data in the database is missing. This can cause issues when this data is required for a query. For example, if a database is built requiring an ID number for every student, it is reasonable to assume a query will be built to pull a student record by that ID number. Such a query would look like:

```
SELECT * from students WHERE studentID = $id
```

If the `$id` is never properly filled in the code, the query would look like this to the server:

```
SELECT * from students WHERE studentID =
```

[www.google.com.tr/](//www.google.com.tr/)